# Spark CSV : insert data into an existing table without changing a specific col

Tags: csv, apache-spark, cassandra

I want to update my database from a csv file publicated every week.
So far I've managed to insert a csv file into my database.

My problems, I will have two more colums that I don't want to touch. One will come from a different CSV File and the other from Solr_query.

So how can I ignore these two columns ?

Example(CSV File):

```
FirstName;Lastname;City
Peter;Johns;New York
```

Example(Table1 the one I have):

```
FirsName-Lastname-City
```

Example(Table2 The one I want)

```
FisrtName-Lastname-City-Age-SolrQuery
```

My code:

```
DataFrame DF = sqlContext
                        .read()
                        .format("csv")
                        .option("delimiter", ";")
                        .option("header", "true")
                        //mv .option("inferschema", "true")
                        .load("file:///home/2.csv");

query = "select firstname, lastname, city from mytable"

DataFrame letsgo = sqlContext.sql(query);

letsgo.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("mytable");
```

It works fine when I have 3 columns but not I my table has 5 columns
What can I do?

Comment: try this letsgo.withColumn("age", lit(null: String)).withColumn("solrquery", lit(null: String)).write().mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("mytable");

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to touch the columns Age and SolrQuery. Your query change Age and SolrQuery and change them to null

Answer (score 0):

Additional columns with null value can be included in query:

```
query = "select firstname, lastname, city, null as Age, null as SolrQuery from mytable"
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to touch the columns Age and SolrQuery. Your query change Age and SolrQuery and change them to null

Comment: Yours initial dataset does not have columns "Age" and "SolrQuery", how query can change them? Guess, yours idea how data will be processed is wrong. 

Maybe, better load "2.csv" in first staging table, file with "Age" and "SolrQuery" in second table, and then join first and second table by query, and store result in "mytable".